# CSS direction for up-side-down?

Tags: html, css

When developing a chat using css you want to have the latest messages to come in the bottom of the page. And the input area under that. We solve it currently by using javascript and scrolling the content to the bottom of the message container.

We do have support for LTR and RTL languages, that works really nice using the css direction property. So where is the USD (up-side-down) direction for vertical alignment of html elements? Is there anything existing already for this?

Answer (score 2):

You could put the messages into a `display: flex;` div that has `flex-direction: column;` and if you want to reverse it make it a `flex-direction: column-reverse;` container.

Comment: This helps but does not solve that one need to still scroll using javascript to keep the container scrolled to the bottom at all times.

Answer (score 0):

For the title of this question, there is the [writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) property.

```css
.vert {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
}
```

```html
<div class="vert">
  <span>I'm vertical</span>
</div>
```

But it's probably not what OP actually needs.

Comment: Correct, that is not what I was looking for :)